# VueJS components not being exported correctly

Tags: javascript, gulp, vue.js, browserify, babeljs

I'm trying to setup VueJS components in a Node/Express app, I'm using Gulp with Browserify in order to import the components.

**Problem:**

My components aren't being exported correctly, after importing them, I try to debug with console.log, like this: `import Home from './home.vue'; console.log(Home);` and it returns this:

```
Object
_Ctor: VueComponent(options)
__proto__: Objec
```

Looking some working example (vue components), it should show method like: `template, ready, data, etc` in this object.

That's why I think my components are not being exported correctly, and the fact that my page is blank, nothing loads inside `<div id="app"></div>`.

**Here are my setup:**

Gulpfile.js:

```
/**
 * Module Dependencies
 */
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
var vueify = require('vueify');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var es = require('event-stream');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var tap = require('gulp-tap');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var babelify = require('babelify');


gulp.task('scripts', function () {

  var b = browserify({
        entries: 'scripts/store.js',
        debug: true,
        transform: [vueify, babelify.configure({presets: ["es2015"], plugins: ["add-module-exports"]})]
    });
    return b.bundle()
        .pipe(source('scripts/store-app.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .on('error', gutil.log)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'));
});

/* Sass task */
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('scss/**.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: ['scss'].concat()
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/stylesheets'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/stylesheets'))
    /* Reload the browser CSS after every change */
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});

/* Reload task */
gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

/* Prepare Browser-sync for localhost */
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], function() {
    browserSync.init(['css/*.css', 'js/*.js'], {
        /*
        I like to use a vhost, WAMP guide: https://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp, XAMP guide: http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/
        */
        proxy: 'localhost:3010',
        port: 5000,
        notify: true,
        /* For a static server you would use this: */

        //server: {
        //    baseDir: './public'
        //}

    });
});

gulp.task('nodemon', function (cb) {
  var called = false;
  return nodemon({
    script: 'app.js',
    ignore: [
      'gulpfile.js',
      'node_modules/'
    ]
  })
  .on('start', function () {
    if (!called) {
      called = true;
      cb();
    }
  })
  .on('restart', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      reload({ stream: false });
    }, 1000);
  });
});

/* Watch scss, js and html files, doing different things with each. */
gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'browser-sync'], function () {
    /* Watch scss, run the sass task on change. */
    gulp.watch(['scss/*.scss', 'scss/**/*.scss'], ['sass'])
    /* Watch app.js file, run the scripts task on change. */
    gulp.watch(['scripts/*.js'], ['scripts'])
    /* Watch .html files, run the bs-reload task on change. */
    gulp.watch(['*.html'], ['bs-reload']);
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "vueify",
      "babelify",
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "./js/vendor/jquery.js": "$",
    "three": "global:THREE"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "browser-sync": "^2.17.5",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-tap": "^0.1.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "tether": "^1.3.7",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "vinyl-transform": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^1.0.26",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^2.0.6",
    "vue-i18n": "^4.7.1",
    "vue-resource": "^0.9.3",
    "vue-router": "^0.7.13",
    "vueify": "^8.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "basic-auth-connect": "^1.0.0",
    "browserify": "^13.1.0",
    "ejs": "^2.5.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.2.1",
    "i18n": "^0.8.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "swagger-client": "^2.1.18",
    "browserify-shim": "~3.2.0"
  }
}
```

app.js

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var VueResource = require('vue-resource');
var VueRouter = require('vue-router');

// Components
import Home from '../home.vue';
console.log(Home);

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueResource);

console.log(Vue);

var router = new VueRouter({
  hashbang: true,
  // history: true,
  transitionOnLoad: true
}); 

router.map({
  '/': { component: Home, name: 'root' }
});

var App = Vue.extend({
});

router.start(App, '#app');
```

home.vue

```
<script>
var Header = require('../header.vue');

export default {
  data () {
  },
  ready () {
  },
  components: {
    'app-header': Header
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    Home
  </div>
</template>
```

index.html.ejs

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>

  <script src="bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Notes:**

1 - If I change my app.js using a inline component like the example below, it works:

```
var Foo = {
    template: '<p>This is foo!</p>'
}
router.map({
  '/': { component: Foo, name: 'root' },
});
```

More one reason I think the problem is on bundled components. In order to do bundle these components and get this structure to work I'm using some tools like: Browserify, Babel, Vueify, Babelify.

Comment: Hi, I got same problem like you. I think it was vue-loader issue